# Google Maps V3 Cluster will not reset after clearMarkers()

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I want to add and remove data sets from the clusterer - but when a particular data set cluster is toggled off the original (non-clustered) markers dont re-appear - i cant make them visible...

```
function clusterEvents(i)
{
    cluster[0][i]=cluster[0][i]?0:1 // to tell which data set is in use
    if(cluster[1]) // clear the cluster
        cluster[1].clearMarkers()
    cluster[1]=new MarkerClusterer(map,[],{gridSize:50,maxZoom:15})
    for(i in iconz) // import markers
    {
        if(iconz[i].type<20)
        {
            if(cluster[0][iconz[i].type]||cluster[0][iconz[i].type-6]) // if target then cluster
                cluster[1].addMarker(iconz[i],true)
            else
                **iconz[i].setVisible(true) // make it visible**
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lay with the syntax of making the markers visible in the code above

```
iconz[i].setVisible(true)
```

the correct syntax is:

```
iconz[i].setOptions({map:map[j_W],visible:true})
```

whats nice about this is that clusters can be assigned to their own layers/arrays and can be toggled on and off